Create counter on Grafana
I'm using Influx DB to store some data, only TRUE and FALSE on a variable. That data is being graphed on Grafana. I would like to implement a counter tht increases any time the FALSE changes to TRUE. I'm a beginner using Influx DB and Grafana. Below is the code I'm using only to graph the TRUE and FALSE values:
from(bucket: "test")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "In_Outs")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "variable_1")


If you only have changes in the database so it's always
true
false
true
false

then a filter and count should be sufficient
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._value == true)
  |> count()

If the same state is stored multiple times
true
true
false
false
false
true

you will need something like
import "influxdata/influxdb/monitor"
...
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with _level: string(v: r._value)}))
  |> monitor.stateChanges(fromLevel: "false", toLevel: "true")
  |> count()

